# How to call list of API's one by one in python and store the data to snowflake

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Suppose I have list of API's like the following...

https://developer.genesys.cloud/devapps/api-explorer#get-api-v2-alerting-alerts-active
https://developer.genesys.cloud/devapps/api-explorer#get-api-v2-alerting-interactionstats-rules
https://developer.genesys.cloud/devapps/api-explorer#get-api-v2-analytics-conversations-details

I want to read this API's one by one and store the data to snowflake using Pandas and SQLalchemy.

Do you have any ideas for reading the API's one by one in my python script?

-Read the API's one by one from a file.

- Load the data to snowflake table directly.